# Jquery + form submit... in a need of fresh set of eyes

Tags: jquery, forms, codeigniter

I do struggle with it as hell. Can someone tell me what is wrong with that code.

In a word: 
CI + jquery form submit. I try to add inline row.

- java part

  ```
      var pair = $('#pair').attr('value');
      var entry = $('#entry').attr('value');
      var exit = $('#exit').attr('value');
      var buysell = $('#buysell').attr('value');
      var pl = $('#pl').attr('value');
  var dataString = 'pair='+ pair +'&entry='+ entry +'&exit='+ exit +'&buysell='+ buysell +'&pl='+ pl;
    $("form#submit").submit(function() {
          $.ajax({ 
              type: "POST",
              url: "<?php echo base_url();?>journal/add",
              data: dataString,
              success: function(){
                      $("#message").text("Added").fadeOut(4000, function() {
                          $(this).css('display','block').text("");
                      });
              }
          });
  });
  ```
- controller part (works if not using java, and yet it's too simple not to work)

  ```
      $data['pair'] = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['pair']));
      $data['entry'] = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['entry']));
      $data['exit'] = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['exit']));
      $data['buysell'] = stripslashes(trim($_POST['buysell']));
      // Insert_data
      $this->journal_model->add_trade($data);
  ```

If someone will be able to help, please do... :(

Cheers,

/Jacek

---

After some woking out... I have it working in IE (wow :O ) but not in Safair/FF/Chrome :S

Function looks like that now:

```
    $("form#add_trade_form").submit(function() {
        dataString = $("form#add_trade_form").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url();?>journal/add",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            lsuccess: function() {
                $("#message").html("Saved... ").fadeOut(4000, function() { 
                    $(this).css('display', 'block').text("");
                });
            }

        });

    });
```

Any ideas?

PS. Thanks Rocky ... it moved me forward...

Comment: What doesn't work?  What's the problem?

Comment: It does not submits... I am new to Java Script... it's way easier to debug php seeing where is the error. Here it does not submits the data to the database.

Comment: So, does the JavaScript post to the PHP file correctly?  Can you `echo $_POST['pair'];`?  There may be a problem in the `journal_model->add_trade` function.

Comment: There is no problem with the function, that is for sure. ... I will echo the results though as I do think there is a problem there.. but why :?

Comment: I just meant test to see if the $_POST array contains the correct data.  I honestly do not know what the problem is.

Comment: I figured out the problem.  The dataString may not be correct if any fields are empty.  See my answer below.

Comment: It's pretty easy to debug javascript too, if you have the right tools. Try firebug for firefox. You can then analyze the XHR stuff to see how the requests are working (or if they even are at all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `$('form').serialize()` instead of manually creating data string.  If any of the fields are empty, your manually created dataString may not be correct.
For example, if the buysell field was empty, the dataString would be `pair=data&entry=data2&exit=data2&buysell=&pl=data3`, as you can see buysell is empty, and this dataString is not valid.

```
$("form#submit").submit(function() {
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>journal/add",
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function(){
                $("#message").text("Added").fadeOut(4000, function() {
                    $(this).css('display','block').text("");
                });
        }
    });
});
```

This can also be written using the `$.post()` shorthand.

```
$.post('<?php echo base_url();?>journal/add', $('form').serialize(), function(){
    $("#message").text("Added").fadeOut(4000, function() {
        $(this).css('display','block').text("");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

the one think that jumps out at me is the php echo statement. is this in a php file? if not, that's your problem.

Comment: The OP is using CodeIginter, and I assume this is in a view file loaded via a controller.  If not, this is your problem.

Comment: This is a build in Code Igniter statement which gets the url configured.

Comment: I know how to use CodeIgniter, I know what `base_url();` does.  Is this code in a view file, or in a .js file?

Comment: OK, I got dumper now, what I did... was to hardcode a string in 
     data: "pair=test&entry=test2"      It worked... once... now it does not submits again :S I did not change anything after that :S :S

Comment: I found out that once I fill the form ... it does not submits ... empty one submits the data hardcoded ... :)

Comment: I figured out the problem.  The dataString may not be correct if any fields are empty.  See my answer below.